# Posts, pages and some images are deleted sometimes

Tags: errors

Hello I'm having trouble with this website https://borinqueneers.com/ sometimes it is broken and when I check from the WP Dashboard I notice all of the post and pages are in the trash also some images are missing then too fix this the hosting restore  it to a point where it is fine it has happen so many time now I can't really figure  out what is happening here any can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your site keeps getting hacked, if the posts and pages are in the trash every now and then? Have your tried changing the passwords for every user, database password, ftp credentials, WP salts and such?

You could try installing WP Security Audit Log plugin (*not affiliated*) from the WordPress plugin repo for tracking all the changes made on your site.